# Check loading time in WebDriver test during execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use `Selenium WebDriver 3.14` and test is executed in `Chrome` browser. I need to measure response time of a page in execution time to check it is under a predefined value. If it is greater than this value some additional actions should be done. So I need different solution than `System.currentTimeMillis()`, because check of this value should be done automatically in background. It is an AJAX like window, so when loading takes too long time, it should be closed by script. Window example:

[image: example window]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical solution to this is a try/catch against a wait.  E.g. if the next step is to click a button that shows once loading completes:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, LOADING_TIMEOUT);

    WebElement webElement;
    try {
        webElement = wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.id(id)));
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        // Close loading window
        return;
    }

    webElement.click();
```

However, there is a common problem if you are using implicit timeouts in Selenium.  This doesn't work too well, particularly if the implicit timeout is longer than the LOADING_TIMEOUT, as this slows down the polling cycle in the `wait.until()`.

In this case, the simplest solution is to temporarily reduce the implicit timeout:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, LOADING_TIMEOUT);

    WebElement webElement;
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        webElement = wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.id(id)));
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        // Delay any further interaction until the timeout has been restored
        webElement = null;
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    if (webElement != null)
        webElement.click();
    else
        // Close loading window
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you could decrease time in `selenium.waitForPageToLoad("100000");` to a wanted predefined value, let us say 20 seconds. So if you want the page loading to stop if it is not loaded in 20 seconds, try something like this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    
try {
      selenium.waitForPageToLoad("20000");
      System.out.println("The page load is too long!");
} catch {
      long timeToLoad= (System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
      System.out.println("The page loaded in " +timeToLoad+ " seconds.");
}
```

Comment: That's very perceptive of you. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should try setting [Logging Preferences](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingPreferences.html) through capability `CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS` for [performance-log](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging/performance-log).

For example:

```
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences(); 
logs .enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
```

you can get performance log entries as below.

```
for (LogEntry entry : driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE)) {
    System.out.println(entry.toString());
    //do the needful
}
```

Comment: Instead of  sysout do what ever process you want to do with log entry, including assertion or reporting.  It will have all performance log entries you need to look for only interested entries during processing.

Comment: it looks that you have modified title as well as the description of the original question. Above answer is to address your original question to get performance logs.

Comment: I didn't modified title of question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for API testing not Automation Testing.

[Postman API Testing Setup and Usage Tutorial](http://toolsqa.com/postman-tutorial/)

Hopefully this will help

edit:

Alternatively, a more lightweight solution for API testing:

[Online API tester](https://apitester.com/)

Comment: No, it is a website, but loading times of a form are sometimes too long. In this case I would like to log this event and take some additional actions.

Comment: Hi there, i believe i understand your question a little better now;



`long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("100000");
long timeToLoad= (System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
if (timeToLoad>10000) System.out.println("Epocrates was slow");`

This is an example used, i believe this might help.

Ultimately, replace the console.log(""); with whatever the action you would like to take, in the time you would like to compare it to.

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568840/best-way-to-time-something-in-selenium

Comment: Hello,
I already use a similar solution, but it gives value only when page is loaded. Loading of page should be terminated if value is greater than predefined value. To do this value should be checked during loading time too.